# Unable to get control or namespace in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have created asp.net web application project using Visual Studio 2019. I have added textbox and button in the new webform.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

In the code behind (.vb) file I am unable to get that control (textbox and button) through IntelliSense.

IntelliSense is also not showing the reference in code behind.

Required help to solve the issue.

Comment: try clean+rebuild of solution, restart VS

Comment: I have tried the same also I have created several test web project to overcome this issue but no result